# How can you generate a log in the Parse console from iOS?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am trying to generate logs in the parse console from an iOS app. This should be pretty simple but I can't seem to find an example of how to accomplish this anywhere. I see that is it possible to set the logging level, but I haven't found other mention in the SDK about logging. Has anyone accomplished this? Sample code in either Swift or Objective-c would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why should it be simple? IIRC the log is for cloud code usage.

Comment: @Wain the note about it being simple was a minor point. Do you have any help to offer?

Comment: Why do you want to use it? I expect you would need to add a cloud function to do it.

Comment: We want to be notified about failed interactions between the ios client and the hardware. I'm sending custom analytics events but these have limited information. I will try your suggestion, building a custom cloud function to generate the log. Thank you.

Comment: I'd be more tempted to create a class for this and upload a new instance. Tracking the log contents and querying it for new entries isn't very easy (though you can get it from the command line).

Comment: Do you find a way to console in Parse from ios? I am in need of the same.